# Create a window that appears above everything else

Tags: windows, electron, desktop-application

I'm trying to create a window that appears at the top of your screen in Windows and everything else is appended below it. The window is very thin so it doesn't get in the way of anything else. I'm not sure if this would work on MacOS but I'm only really worry about windows.

I'm using electronjs to do this. I've gone through the documentation and can't find anything so was wondering if anyone else has any ideas.

I've seen other applications do this but I'm not sure what they are built in.

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for? https://electronjs.org/docs/all#winsetalwaysontopflag-level-relativelevel

Answer (score 0):

Use `alwaysOnTop` property of [`BrowserWindow`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#new-browserwindowoptions)

```
let win = new BrowserWindow({
  // ...
  alwaysOnTop: true
})
```

---

If you want to only display things on your window and forward mouse input to windows below, use [`win.setIgnoreMouseEvents(true)`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#winsetignoremouseeventsignore-options), too

Comment: But then the window will always be on top of other applications? I want the window to be appended to the top of the screen and all application to be below. Kind like making a toolbar that always sits are the top of your screen and doesn't get in the way of anything.

Comment: 1. "But then the window will always be on top of other applications?" yes. You can make it transparent and ignoring mouse to not distract other applications. 

2. "appended ... all application to be below", you cannot control window size of other applications from Electron obviously.